# About animating a skined rigged character

Tags: animation

I'm new here and new to animation in blender. My question is, is it possible to animate a part of the character when they are already skinned and rigged? I'm talking about animating the actual model, not the bones or rigging.

for example. I select my character and go into edit mode, then apply a keyframe to a part of their skin, than move that skin out to create a bulge, and then create another keyframe.

Is it possible or not after rigging?

Any help in understanding would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I will try shape keys. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shape keys, example:

[image]

You can also use the *Animall* addon to animate vetices, it may be more flexible than shape keys.